# Differences between CSS3 :hover and :focus?

Tags: css, focus, hover, css-selectors, pseudo-class

The  [**CSS3 doc**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) talks about :hover and :focus, which seem exactly the same to me. What are the differences between the two? What am I not seeing?

Thanks!

Comment: `:hover` and `:focus` were introduced in CSS level 2, and their specs haven't been changed in CSS3.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Hover is 'true' when the mouse pointer is over an element. Focus is true if the cursor is in that element. It's possible for hover to be false and focus true (e.g click in a text field then move the mouse away)

Comment: Yes, I'd forgotten the click-then-move-the-mouse action. Also the possibility of tabbing to a field. Thanks.

Comment: To avoid any confusion: "cursor" here means "caret". :)

Comment: For completeness: Not all controls have an insertion point when they're focused. Links and buttons can also have focus.

Comment: The answer you gave led me to a solution for a similar problem that included the "click and drag away". Using a:focus and a:hover were not sufficient. I had to use "a:hover:focus" to ensure that I had both true!

Comment: a:hover and a:focus is the same thing? (since you can not be inside an a element)

Answer (score 12):

`:hover` applies to any element that the mouse cursor is currently over.  `:focus` refers to form focus, and is the current form element with focus.  Roughly speaking, if you start typing, which element will you be filling?

Answer (score 8):

The different between `:hover` and `:focus` is:

`:hover` when your mouse pointer is on the element.

`:focus` when you select an element, the element gets into the focus.

More Information: [CSS Pseudo Classes at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Answer (score 1):

hover only applies when the pointing device is over the element. The doc makes that quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

Hover you can add with  % percentages with transition timing with the new css3 technology. Expect IE9 all major browsers will support them. 
here are some samples of two navigation menus to understand hover and animation on hover and also the fading of the colors in css3 hover attribute.
`

Comment: I've removed your non-disclosed links to your own blog. Please see the Self-Promotion area of the FAQ before posting any more answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hover is particularly about **Mouse Pointer**:

Example when Mouser pointer is **over** / *(on the)*  **Button**, **for that button hover** is **true**.

Focus is about the **highlighting** element:

Usually when we use tab key to change the focus of an element.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "**contrasting difference**" between the two:

**`Hover`**-When your mouse pointer **hover(wave or float)** over a particular element.

*and*

**`Focus`**-When you **select an element**,then the element gets into focus.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between these two things i.e. hover and the focus is:

hover:-  when you take your mouse pointer is on the particular element such as button, text-field etc.

focus:- when you select an element or click an event that time it changes its original state and looks different.

Comment: This is already present in the other answers just with different words. Would you care to reason why this is better than the other answers?