# Exclude a pseudo-class from transition in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions

Is it possible to **exclude a pseudo-class** having the same property as another pseudo-class **from being transitioned**?
Please look at the following example code for your reference:

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 1s ease-in 500ms;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="transition">Submit</button>
```

What if I want to have the transition to be applied on the `:hover` pseudo-class but not on the `:focus` pseudo-class?

[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srishtigupta/kesnLq6a/14/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `transition: none;` on `:focus`

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 1s ease-in 500ms;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: green;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="transition">Submit</button>
```

You can also move the `transition: all 1s ease-in 500ms;` in the `:hover` section but you will still need the `transition: none;` on `:focus` because `:focus` only happens when you also `:hover`

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 1s ease-in 500ms;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: green;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="transition">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The one for which the code snippet is provided works perfectly fine. However moving the `transition` property inside `:hover` makes the element transition out instantaneously unlike the beginning of the transition. 
Additionally, in a general sense, we can `:focus` on an element without `:hover`. Another SO thread that explains why - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143782/differences-between-css3-hover-and-focus.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the transition property to `button:not(:focus)`:

```css
button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
}

button:not(:focus) {
  transition: all 1s ease-in 500ms;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="transition">Submit</button>
```

Comment: If I'm interpreting it correctly, `button:not(:focus)` will select all pseudo-classes on `button` except `:focus` and will apply the relevent CSS properties written inside its block. Suppose I have 4 pseudo-classes - A, B, C, D, out of which, I want to apply transition to A & B but not to B & C. Will a similar approach work if I had multiple pseudo-classes to be excluded for transition?

Comment: [:not()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) just means 'in all cases other than this one', so it would also work when no pseudo-classes apply. To your point, you would simply exclude what you want to exclude: `button:not(:B):not(:C)`.